# Word.Table in VBA, Change TableStyle

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table` and I want it to have the style of one of the Default "`Quicktables`" of Word.

QuickTables = Insert -> Table -> QuickTables

In German the QuickTable is called "Matrix", I think it should be the same in English.

How do I make my Table have this Style in my VB application?

Answer (score 0):

These are BuildingBlocks. You can see that if you record a macro while inserting an entry from the list. That will also give you the (VBA) syntax for inserting a "Quick Table".

Note 1: the exact file path will vary, depending on the version of Office and the user's system configuration (IT might change the default path where the BuildingBlocks template is stored). Here's a result from my system:

```
    Application.Templates( _
    "C:\Users\[profile designation]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\14\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" _
    ).BuildingBlockEntries("Calendar 2").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, _
    RichText:=True
```

Note 2: The BuildingBlock name probably differs according to the UI language. If your code should run in various languages you'll need to research the literal strings, store them, and call the relevant one according to the `WordApplication.Language` (the 1033 in the file path, above, for example, is the LangaugeID for my installation).

Note 3: For VB.NET replace "Application" with the object variable name you're using for Word.Application. Also, parentheses are needed for the Insert method: Insert(Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True)